# I am searching for the source code to libj2d-gtk-linux-i386-2.0.0.so

Tags: shared-library, source-code

I am looking for the source code to *libj2d-gtk-linux-i386-2.0.0.so* which is reported to be contained in a file named *GtkGraphics2DFactory.c*.  This library is an SWT 2 Java bit of glue that is found in Jaspersoft Studio CE.  The library itself I can find.  I need the source to determine if it is possible to port Studio to FreeBSD.

Comment: I came across [this](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/QHsNncCWXs/), from [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/holongate/), but I'm not sure if that's what you're actually after.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I found the source and header files in `/org.holongate.eclipse.j2d.gtk_0.5.0/jni/`

Comment: Add that as the answer and I will accept it.  Again I very much appreciate this.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I'll keep an eye out to see if you have any success with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the source and header files in `/org.holongate.eclipse.j2d.gtk_0.5.0/jni/` if you download the .zip file [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/holongate/).

To find it, for future reference, I searched for `J2D4SWT sourcecode`. That led me to [Java2D for SWT Eclipse Plugins](https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_holongate/downloads/Java2D%20for%20SWT%20%28Eclipse%203.0.X%29/2.3.0%20%28final%29/J2D4SWT_2.3.0.src.zip/) here, which was actually linking to the SourceForge link above.

Comment: It is an older version, but it should be a good start.

Comment: The most recent version of this library is 2.0.0.  It is shipped as a binary to support eclipse on W32 platforms,;or at least to keep the build happy.  For other platforms it is no longer referred to.  A dead end.